# Golang parsefiles not working when run in a docker setup in kubernetes

Tags: docker, go, kubernetes, templates

I have the following directory structure:

```
templates/
  a.tmpl
services/
  service.go
main.go
```

Now inside the `service.go` file i am calling the below function:

```
dir, err := filepath.Abs(filepath.Dir("./templates/"))
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }


    baseFile := filepath.Join(dir, "a.tmpl")

tmpl, err := template.New("base").ParseFiles(baseFile)
```

now the above function is parsing my `a.tmpl` file as expected.

but once this service is up on docker and kubernetes, i am no longer able to open the file since the file does not exists

why is that?

UPDATE:

```
FROM golang:1.16-buster AS builder
# Copy the code from the host and compile it
WORKDIR $GOPATH/src/github.com/me/report
COPY . ./
# pack templates to binary
RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux go build -mod vendor -ldflags "-X github.com/me/report/cmd.version=$(cat .VERSION)" -o /app .

FROM xyz.amazonaws.com/common/platform/base:latest as prod
COPY --from=builder /app ./
ADD ./migrations /migrations
ENTRYPOINT ["/app"]
```

Comment: is dir 'templates'  build to docker-image? show your dockerfile

Comment: could you share the content of the `Dockerfile` and the `docker-compose.yaml` if exists?

Comment: i have included my dockerfile

Comment: maybe you should copy from builder the template folder, like `COPY --from=builder ./templates ./templates`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just copy the templates folder from the builder, like:

```
COPY --from=builder /app ./
ADD ./migrations /migrations
COPY --from=builder ./templates /templates
```

or add the folder like:

```
COPY --from=builder /app ./
ADD ./migrations /migrations
ADD ./templates /templates
```

Answer (score 3):

When you [build](https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/go#hdr-Compile_packages_and_dependencies) your binary, go only includes the necessary go files to have your program work. It does not know that your `templates` directory is necessary to the running of the program.

There is several solutions to your problem :

- Create an environment variable pointing to were the templates are and use it on runtime.
- Embed the `templates` directory into your binary using the [embed package](https://golang.google.cn/pkg/embed/) so that you can access the files at runtime